# How to write plain match expression in doctrine ODM

Tags: mongodb, doctrine-odm

I have big pipeline that Im writing now into doctrine ODM, currently with the pipeline Im getting to these kind of documents:

```
{
"_id":"M-1ea13520-7c30-4482-b5bf-2f8467aa1735",
"chatId":"C-91772cdf-c10b-4faa-9536-98a65554356c",
"publishedAt":{"$date":{"$numberLong":"1696322511000"}},
"lastSeen":{"$date":{"$numberLong":"1696204800000"}}
}
```

Now Im just trying to make a simple match query that works in plain mongodb and looks like this:

```
{
    $match:
      {
        $expr: {
          $lt: ["$lastSeen", "$publishedAt"],
        },
      },
  },
```

This works and now Im simply trying to transcribe this into doctrine ODM like this:

```
->match()->field('$lastSeen')->lt('$publishedAt')
```

but I keep getting error: `unknown top level operator: $lastSeen. If you have a field name that starts with a '$' symbol, consider using $getField or $setField.`

What can I do about this, how do you do this in doctrine ODM?

Answer (score 0):

Ok managed to do it on my own:

```
->match()->addAnd(['$expr' => ['$lt' => ['$lastSeen', '$publishedAt']]])
```